# How to download Service Fabric certificate?

Tags: azure, ssl, azure-service-fabric

I'm working on `Azure Service Fabric` ,
It is already created and in `Security tab` I can able to see `Primary certificate` and `Thumbprint` as well.

I want to know How can I download this certificate and import it into my local machine.

As `Cloud explorer` giving me error:

> Cloud Explorer could not connect to cluster 'Testcluster': Unable to
>   find a matching client certificate. Make sure you have the certificate
>   installed on this machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this step by step explanation [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-secure-azure-cluster-with-certs/).

You'll need to [import](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754489(v=ws.11).aspx) that certificate you uploaded to key vault into your local certificate store too.