# From where I can download certificate in order to publish app from Visual Studio to Azure

Tags: c#, azure, azure-service-fabric, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to publish my service fabric application from Visual Studio to Azure. I was looking at this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v2FJsB0mnrI) where (around 5:10) authors talk about installing certificate on local machine. But he never showed from where I need to download the certificate.

Please let me know location from where I can download the certificate in order to publish code from Visual studio to Azure Service Fabric cluster.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this help? https://github.com/Azure/Service-Fabric-Troubleshooting-Guides/blob/master/Security/Download%20certificate%20from%20Keyvault%20in%20PFX%20or%20PEM%20or%20CER%20format.md Or this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/38652373/1537195

Comment: Also here: https://dontpaniclabs.com/blog/post/2019/03/28/provisioning-your-first-azure-service-fabric-cluster/

Comment: I tried the steps mentioned in dontpaniclabs.com/blog/post/2019/03/28/… link but Azure is throwing Failed to submit updates for certificate error. when I try to add certificate to Azure Cluster from Key Vault.